# Prevent Windows 11 Pro 22H2 from automatically adjusting screen brightness

Tags: windows-11, brightness, windows-11-v22h2

A few days after installing Windows 11 Pro 22H2 I have noticed that whenever I am playing some video or listening to a louder music, my screen brightness gets automatically bumped to 100%. Since I am working in a quite a dark environment with brightness usually set around 37% to 49% such bumps makes me really wako. How to prevent it?

Any source that I managed to find and read including:

- [Windows keeps changing brightness automatically](https://ugetfix.com/ask/fix-windows-keeps-changing-brightness-automatically/) (3 methods)
- [Content adaptive brightness control in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/content-adaptive-brightness-control-in-windows-292d1f7f-9e02-4b37-a9c8-dab3e1727e78)
- [Change screen brightness in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-screen-brightness-in-windows-3f67a2f2-5c65-ceca-778b-5858fc007041)

are simply not working (or cannot be even applied) because Windows 11 22H2 introduced many changes to Settings and system design that makes all these guides off-topic and obsolete. Mainly:

- Settings > Display does not have the *[Change brightness automatically when lighting changes](https://ugetfix.com/ask/fix-windows-keeps-changing-brightness-automatically/#qm-h2-1)* option

[image]

- Settings > Battery has the *[Lower screen brightness while in battery saver](https://ugetfix.com/ask/fix-windows-keeps-changing-brightness-automatically/#qm-h2-2)* checkbox (and I have unchecked it), but I'd like to prevent Windows from **increasing** screen brightness automatically rather than **decreasing** it.
- Disabling adaptive brightness via Control Panel is [not possible](https://ugetfix.com/ask/fix-windows-keeps-changing-brightness-automatically/#qm-h2-3) because my *Power Options: Advanced Settings* dialog box has no *Enable adaptive brightness* key in the *Display* group and no sign of birightness-related settings in the *Battery* group:

[image]

- Disabling this feature via *Settings > System > Display* is [not possible](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/content-adaptive-brightness-control-in-windows-292d1f7f-9e02-4b37-a9c8-dab3e1727e78) because Windows 11 22H2 the *Help improve battery by optimizing the content shown and brightness* check box and the *Display* item itself is not clickable (to reveal some advanced settings).
- Same thing repeated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-screen-brightness-in-windows-3f67a2f2-5c65-ceca-778b-5858fc007041) twice.

What else can I do or try in order to block Windows 11 22H2 from automatically changing or increasing brightness in my PC?

Comment: no sign of birightness-related settings in the Battery group:  ..... Update the Power Driver (Manufacturer's Driver Update App). Also update BIOS at the same time.

Comment: This (probably) has nothing together with the driver, because this problem started to happen just a week or two ago, when I installed W11 22H2. Previously I had absolutely no such problems. And the graphic or power driver was not updated recently. I am pretty sure that this is another pesky thing that Windows 11 update has introduced.